# Button working on simulator but not in physical device

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make use of the buttons on my app, but apparently they don't work on a physical device, I cannot press them. In the simulator it is indeed possible to press them, but not sure why not in the physical device.

This is the following code I'm using:

```
                <ScrollView refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                    />
                }>
                    <View style={{ padding: 20, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("the button works.")}>
                            <View style={styles.addHomework}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Add Homework</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={{ paddingLeft: 3 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removeSubject()}>
                            <View style={styles.removeSubject}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Remove Subject</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

Comment: can you provide TouchableOpacity's import

Comment: @mainak `import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";`

Comment: change that to import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

will work

Comment: @mainak tried... still nothing :(